# How to return all key / value pairs for multiple record ids (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables with the following structure...

```
Table cellphone_tokens:
-----------
| id (pk) |
| model   |
-----------

Table cellphone_keys_vals:  
-----------
| cell_id |
| key     |
| value   |
-----------
```

`cell_id` is the `id` of the corresponding model in the first table. I've also entered the `model` again in the second table for convenience.

Suppose I need to select all the `keys` and `values` for a specific `model` (or, up to 4 models). How am I able to write a query to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner query:

```
SELECT
 v.*
FROM cellphone_keys_vals AS v
WHERE v.cell_id IN (
    SELECT
          t.id
    FROM cell_phone_tokens as t
            WHERE t.model IN ("model1", "model2")
      )
```

Comment: Hey Simendsjo... I used the following: SELECT  `key`, `value` 
 FROM wp_cellphone_keys_vals 
 LEFT JOIN wp_cellphone_tokens 
 ON `wp_cellphone_tokens`.`id` = `wp_cellphone_keys_vals`.`cell_id`
 WHERE `wp_cellphone_tokens`.`model` IN ('E8',  'W850i'). Is it similar to what you have suggested?

Comment: @Rutwick: Yes. This example was first a limit by in the subselect as I thought your question was "limit to 4 phones", not models. I just didn't change my answer after I corrected it to models. I would have used your join instead of this :)

Comment: Thanks Simendsjo! Models and phones are the same! I just used the term phones instead of models! :)  And I have another sql problem (!)... When I delete an entry from my tables (any one from the middle but not the last entry) and then insert a new entry, my query values are reordered... Doesn't happen if I truncate the table and start afresh or if I delete the last entry and enter a new one... Is it because the keys/vals table doesn't have an index?

Comment: Correct. As long as you don't explicitly tell MySql to order your answer, the result is undefined and can vary. Add an ORDER BY clause to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't stick the `model` field in 2 places. It makes it harder to ensure data integrity and it doesn't take advantage of the 'relational' part of relational database.

Secondly, it appears that you are using a vertical schema for your cellphone_keys_vals table.  This can be useful if there are piles of keys that don't get used very often.  But it is more common, and more efficient to use a horizontal schema where each key is a field. So say there are 3 'keys': colour, price, size.  Your cellphone_key_values table becomes a `cellphone` table:

```
cell_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
token_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
colour VARCHAR(10),
price DECIMAL(5,2),
size ENUM('s','m','l'),
CONSTRAINT `FK_cellphone1` FOREIGN KEY (`token_id`) REFERENCES `cellphone_tokens` (`id`)
```

Then it's easy:

```
SELECT c.cell_id, t.model, c.colour, c.size, c.price FROM
cellphones c JOIN cellphone_tokens t ON (c.token_id=t.id)
```

gets ALL the cellphones, including their models.  If you want to limit to a particular set of models, you can add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT c.cell_id, t.model, c.colour, c.size, c.price FROM
cellphones c JOIN cellphone_tokens t ON (c.token_id=t.id)
WHERE t.model IN ('blah','foo','bar')
```

If you want to limit to maximum 4 models *and* you don't care which models, something like this could work:

```
SELECT c.cell_id, t.model, c.colour, c.size, c.price FROM
cellphones c JOIN cellphone_tokens t ON (c.token_id=t.id)
WHERE t.model IN (SELECT id FROM cellphone_tokens ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4);
```

Note that `ORDER BY rand()` is pretty inefficient so if your cellphone_tokens table will have many rows, it's not a good option.

Comment: Hi dnagirl... Thanks a lot! I was using the horizontal schema when I had a fixed number of properties (with each column representing a property). But then I had to change it to use the vertical schema (keys, vals) because the requirement was updated and the user wanted to be able to add new properties (in addition to the fixed ones) for a cellphone if he wants to. It resulted in an excessively wide and complicated table structure (unpredictable number of extra properties per cell!). With the key/value approach I found it easier to add new properties without modifying the table structure.

Comment: So with a little mess (!), I did the following: SELECT  `key`, `value` 
 FROM wp_cellphone_keys_vals 
 LEFT JOIN wp_cellphone_tokens 
 ON `wp_cellphone_tokens`.`id` = `wp_cellphone_keys_vals`.`cell_id`
 WHERE `wp_cellphone_tokens`.`model` IN ('E8',  'W850'). I just checked the number of cellphones requested for viewing and inserted them in the IN part.